# Issue in displaying video js video inside bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, video.js

**Modal is display Proper but when i click on modal. That video and video control are messed up. Please suggest if any other suitable way if i am done it wrong.**

I have got one library which is good and display video but id does not give any option to close popup like bootstrap modal does.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Popup Video</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .video-js .vjs-tech {
          position: relative;
          height: inherit;
        }
        .player {
          width: 80%;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
          background:black;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
    
    
      <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
    
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <p> test </p>
          <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" width="640" height="264"
      poster="https://d9wrv003o8xvb.cloudfront.net/thumb_0801180537104122.jpg" data-setup='{}'>
        <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
        <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/webm'>
        <p class="vjs-no-js">
          To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
          <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
        </p>
      </video>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.6.3/video.js"></script>
    
     <script>
      
     </script>
    
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

I attach image here that shows how controls messed up.

[Messed control image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgqdW.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference the VideoJS stylesheet: https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.2.3/video-js.css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Popup Video</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.2.3/video-js.css">
  <style>
    .video-js .vjs-tech {
      position: relative;
      height: inherit;
    }
    
    .player {
      width: 80%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      background: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>


  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p> test </p>
          <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" width="640" height="264" poster="https://d9wrv003o8xvb.cloudfront.net/thumb_0801180537104122.jpg" data-setup='{}'>
        <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
        <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/webm'>
        <p class="vjs-no-js">
          To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
          <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
        </p>
      </video>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>



  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.6.3/video.js"></script>

  <script>
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```